# inputbox change value event looks like not firing in asp.net razor bounded with bootstrap datetimepicker with eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a textbox bound with datetime picker. What I have to do is on change of value in the text box if another input textbox (which also bound with datetimepicker) is empty I have to fill the value from initial textbox.

I am trying following but no alert coming:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document)
    .off("change", "#FirstDate")
    .on("change", "#FirstDate", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input id="FirstDate" name="FirstDate" type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="FirstDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
  </div>
  <span asp-validation-for="FirstDate" class="error"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Second Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input id="SecondDate" name="SecondDate" type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="SecondDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
  </div>
  <span asp-validation-for="SecondDate" class="error"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the order of the jquery script-block and the divs for the date the same as in your example? If so, move the script part to the end or change it to a `$(document).ready(()  => { ... })`. If not: Your example isn't working because of this.

Comment: it is already in the end inside script section

Answer (score 1):

You should always run the script only when it knows what to refer to.
The script part, is executed syncronous and has to come after the divs or needs a trigger where the elements are present at the dom. If it is executed straight at this point, jquery won't find the elements and can't add the listener.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input id="FirstDate" name="FirstDate" type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="FirstDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
  </div>
  <span asp-validation-for="FirstDate" class="error"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Second Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input id="SecondDate" name="SecondDate" type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="SecondDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
  </div>
  <span asp-validation-for="SecondDate" class="error"></span>
</div>



<script>
  $(document)
    .off("change", "#FirstDate")
    .on("change", "#FirstDate", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: dear it is not working when i have a datetimepicker attached. <span class="input-group-addon"></span> have an image which fire datetimepicker event which populate the date in the input box

Comment: looks like problem with eonasdan